# For loop is only creating one image?

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, picturebox

So I've created this loop to print out a map. It's pretty archaic and I've simplified the code on what images are called - but in essence, for each co-ordinate (X,Y), to create a new picturebox with the relevant image.

I've attempted to create an array of pictureboxes so that each item is unique, but it was the same error.

So the actual issue itself is that I'm only getting one image (the first iteration) to show up every time. I've checked that it's a unique (X,Y) for each iteration, and that it's actually running through multiple iterations - which it is.

So if all of the iterations are definitely being printed out, and they're definitely not on the same location, what on earth is the issue? Many thanks.

```
    For MapY As Integer = 0 To WorldParameter 'This parameter can be between 80 and 800, depending on settings. Is on 80 for testing.
        For MapX As Integer = 0 To WorldParameter
            Dim BaseTile As PictureBox = New PictureBox
            BaseTile.Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\CLEO\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Corruption\Corruption\mapimage\motorway.png")
            BaseTile.Location = New Point(MapX * 10, MapY * 10) 'The image is 10x10; ergo the *10 increment
            BaseTile.Visible = True
            Me.Controls.Add(BaseTile)
        Next
    Next
```

[image: The Problem]

Comment: I smell code dump without debugging. Did you check the size of each control? Do the code reside in the `Form.Load` method?

Comment: I'm not familiar with debugging or control sizes. It's in a   Button.click.

Comment: you do not set the width and height of the picturebox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing an issue of boxes overlapping each other.

Set an explicit `BaseTile.Size` of `New Size(10, 10)` (or however big you want your `PictureBox` objects to be).

You could also (instead) set the `Width` and `Height` manually, but that's much less fun.